# Spring Conditional Caching with Local Variables?

Tags: spring-cache

I have a Cacheable method that returns an object containing data from multiple sources.
In case of an error (ex: A source is unavailable), it will return with whatever partial data was retrieved.
However, I do not want this result to be cached. I have a Boolean that determines whether the result contains full or partial data.

How can I reference this local Boolean variable inside the `unless` annotation parameter?

Below is an example of my issue, referencing the Book code snippets in the [Spring documentation - Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)...

```
// Do not cache book if it's missing pages

@Cacheable(cacheNames="book", unless="#root.target.isMissingPages") //this doesn't work
public Book findBook(String name) {
    Book book = bookShelf.get(name);

    boolean isMissingPages = checkMissingPages(book);
    if (isMissingPages) {
        book.setTitle(book.title + " Missing Pages!");
    }

    return book;
}
```

I've tried using SpEL (I don't fully understand it) inside the `unless` parameter, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The `unless` parameter is evaluated after the method has been called and you can use it on the method `result` i.e. in your case in order not to cache **Book** with missing pages, your `unless` expression should look like following:

```java
@Cacheable(cacheNames="book", unless="#result.isMissingPages")
public Book findBook(String name) {
...
}
```

Comment: My understanding is `#result` is referencing the returned object (Book in this case). If Book does not contain `isMissingPages` (it's only declared in the method), can it still be referenced in `#result`?

Comment: You are correct... I've overlooked this part. So in order to conditionally include Book in your cache, you should move your logic from checkMissingPages() function to the Book itself, if possible. Or just check the title in Book ending with `"Missing Pages!"`